# Can't get any sound from Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I can't get any kind of sound from my PC. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my somewhat old desktop as the soundcard wasn't recognised by my (unlicensed) Windows 7. Ubuntu seems to have detected my card, as it shows up in the sound settings menu, and also in alsamixer (which isn't muted). I've tried all of the outputs on back and front of the machine, to no avail.

Could one of you kind people tell me what the next step is?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure the sound card works?  If it doesn't work under Windows or Ubuntu it could be defective.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ALSA on your system the I suppose you've installed Xubuntu or Lubuntu and not Ubuntu LTS. Ubuntu LTS comes with pulse audio which should be present on your system. If you want to keep ALSA as default then you must install some extra packages. You need 'gnome alsa mixer', 'esound' and quite a few other packages that can boost ALSA.

You should try first 'pulse audio' and install all software needed for pulse-audio to work. It does not generate conflicts with ALSA, and you can remove pulse-audio if you are not satisfied. You should consider disabling all hardware-accelerated features for your sound card if it is some legacy card that do not support hardware-acceleration. Pulse Audio has a built-in module especially for this kind of problems that old sound card have.

This is a good link to help you fix sound problems in Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (Precise Pangolin) or later: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure